# Can not get values of an array from an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, object

I tried to get values from an array from an object but it doesn't work. Can someone help me.

Here is the JSON parse:

```
  let userContent = null;
  try {
    userContent = JSON.parse(entity.contactform_content);
  } catch (e) {
    userContent = String(userContent);
  }
```

Return:

```
"contactform_id": "118",
"contactform_content": 
"{\"display_name\":\"Peter\",\"user_email\":\"peter@gmail.com\",\"user_nation\":\"be\",
\"category\":[{\"name\":\"Chinese Astrology\",\"value\":\"Chinese Astrology\"},{\"name\":\"Karmic Astrology\",\"value\":\"Karmic Astrology\"},{\"name\":\"Horoscopes\",\"value\":\"Horoscopes\"}],
\"available_time\":\"4 hours\",
\"time_slot\":\"2 hours\"}",   
}
```

My attempt to get category value:

```
<TextField
autoComplete="off"
label="Category"
value={userContent.category}
/>
```

[image: It doesn't show category values]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
<TextField
  autoComplete="off"
   label="Category"
  value={userContent.category.map(x => x.name)}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works with the first element of the array. What if I want all elements sir.

Comment: Do you want to display all the categories names in the same TextField value?

Comment: Yes. I tried map the array but it doesn't work.

Comment: In the same TextField or multiples TextField's ?

Comment: In the same textfield. Like: "Chinese Astrology, Karmic Astrology, Horoscopes"

Comment: ok give me a sec and i will update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245703/discussion-between-sonetlumiere-and-lxbster).